# How to convert a Dataset<String> to JavaRDD<String> in Spark java

Tags: apache-spark

I need to convert a Dataset to JavaRDD

I tried converting using toJavaRDD() method but it is not working in Spark java
JavaRDD jrdd = DS.toJavaRDD();

Comment: converting Dataset<String> to JavaRDD<String> using toJavaRDD() method is not giving any compilation error,but when I used the JavaRDD to write into kafka topic the job is falling .Any suggestion/idea how to convert it in a correct way.

Comment: Can you explain what error message you are receiving?

Comment: Spark Context : ERROR initializing spark context .scala-2.11/jar does not exist ;make sure spar is built